# How can I get the first document ID from a firebase collection, which is not equal to a given ID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have `'users'` collection which contains documents of each user ID. I've also stored the current user's ID in a `userID` variable using the authenticated user's ID (anonymously signed in).

I need to get one document ID (not the document data) based on a counter of the lowest value (document data item within this collection), and store it in a variable called 'receiverID', but if the document ID equals the current user's ID, then I would like to get the next available ID.

For example, if there are 3 users on my platform (A, B, and C) and the following 'counter' values exist:

- A: 1, B: 2, C: 3

theoretically, when A queries the collection, they will get their own doc ID back. I would then need to get the second document available within the 'users' collection.

I've begun with the following but am stuck:

```
receiverID = db.collection('users').orderBy('Questions Received','asc').limit(1)
```

Also, this is triggered on an event listener (when a user submits a question), so the 'receiverID' must be resolved before the next part of the function. This is what my event listener looks like:

```
const sayForm = document.querySelector('#say-form');
sayForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection('message').add({
        message: sayForm.sayInput.value,
        time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        sender: userID,
        currentReceiver: receiverID,
        received: 1
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mind fixing the indentation and add more formatting to what are the attributes in a single document, using backticks? Improving the formatting will help to clarify the question too

Comment: @ralemos was able to format. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve for it by doing the following:

```
function getNextReceiver() {
  db.collection('users')
    .orderBy('Messages Received','asc')
    .limit(2)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      let x = querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
      let y = querySnapshot.docs[1].id;
      if (x == userID) {
        receiverID = y
      } else {
        receiverID = x;
      }
    });
    
}

getNextReceiver();
```

By limiting the search results to 2 and saving them in a variable, I was able to compare against the 'userID' and set the 'receiverID' accordingly as the one that did not match.

Answer (score 1):

There is no different operator for queries in Firestore, so you have to fetch the first document and if it's not the expected documentID fetch the next one and so on. You can do that by doing something like the following:

```
receiverID = this.getNextReceiver();

function getNextReceiver() {
    db.collection('users')
      .orderBy('Questions Received','asc')
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
          if(doc.id == userID){
              var validId = false;
              var tempDoc = doc;
              while(!validId){
                  db.collection('users')
                    .orderBy('Questions Received','asc')
                    .startAfter(tempDoc)
                    .limit(1)
                    .get()
                    .then(function (newDoc) {
                        if(newDoc.id != userID){
                            validId = true;
                            return newDoc.id;
                        }
                        tempDoc = newDoc;
                    });
                  
              }
          }
          return doc.id;
      });
}
```

All this run synchronously. Regarding your submit, it cannot be guaranteed that receiverID will be populated since it is trigger by an event, so you will have to either create a scenario where that value is not populated, or block user interaction until it is populated.

**NOTE**: All this code is untested but should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Slight change in the above (remove the additional "(" in the final sub function). This is a good starting point and definitely a more effective way than I envisioned (using wait times and all). Feels safer putting the 'receiverID' variable after the function. However, I get this issue when I try to call the 'getNextReceiver' function now. This is the error: VM1084:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: getNextReceiver is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: As an secondary question, where do you look up how to troubleshoot such an error?

Comment: I edited the answer with a fix for the error you were getting (which was missing the `this.` when calling the function) and removing the extra `(`, thanks for pointing that out, it should work now. Indeed, I also found that using the `promise.then()` is better instead of awaiting the return of those, specially in your case that has to stack promise on top of promise, I fell this is less error prone.

Comment: To your second question, I usually do a google search that points me to some other community posts with a similar problems and solutions and I try to adapt, Also blogs and documentation usually help as well. Please remember to upvote and accept the answer if fixed the issue you were facing.

Comment: Ok so the good news is that error went away. Now I end up with 'undefined' when I try to log the 'receiverID'. I ensured my DB has a few user profiles with values for this field as well.

Comment: try to log the values returning in the `getNextReceiver()` function, if there is value on them, than that means that you are logging receiverID before it's populated. You could mitigate that by populating `receiverID` inside the functions and not returning a value.

Comment: I appreciate your help. it certainly helped me get on the right track in thinking about this and solving for it. I've got to learn more about promises to incorporate in future logic.